# Where to put the array of the icons?

Tags: php, arrays

I currently have this piece of code that works fine. However, as you can see in the screenshot, the foreach shows four instead of one icon.

Where should I put this foreach so that it only shows an icon but still recognizes the variable $specialisatie?

Unfortunately I can't get out.

```
                            if ($results) {
                            foreach ($specs as $specialisatie) {
                                $output = '<tr>';
                                $output .= '<th scope="row">';

                                $sqlArray = "SELECT `specs` FROM leden WHERE `user_id` = $iedeetjee";
                                $statementArray = $conn->prepare($sqlArray);
                                $statementArray->execute();
                                $arrayResults = $statementArray->fetchAll();

                                foreach ($arrayResults as $keyArray => $valueArray) {

                                    $array = $valueArray['specs'];
                                    $array = json_decode($array, true);

                                    foreach ($array as $finalKeyArray => $finalValueArray) {
                                        if ($finalValueArray === 1 && $finalKeyArray == $specialisatie) {
                                            $output .= '<i class="fas fa-check fa-lg text-success row-center"></i>';
                                        } else {
                                            $output .= '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg text-danger row-center"></i>';
                                        }
                                    }
                                }

                                $output .= '</th>';
                                $output .= '<td>';
                                $output .= $specialisatie;
                                $output .= '</td>';
                                $output .= '<td class="editSpec" id="' . $specialisatie . '" name="' . $iedeetjee . '">';
                                $output .= '<i class="hoverable fas fa-edit fa-lg text-primary row-center"></i>';
                                $output .= '</td>';

                                echo $output;
                            }
                        }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASzlh.png

Comment: What?? What are you expecting? I see 16 + 4 icons. What should it be?

Comment: http://img.stevensmax.nl/chrome_3aQlrOrH7J.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of dealing with each and every value use a flag that is false by default and if something makes it true then break the loop.

```
$flag = false;
foreach ($array as $finalKeyArray => $finalValueArray) {
    if ($finalValueArray === 1 && $finalKeyArray == $specialisatie) {
        $flag  = true;
        break;
    }
}
if($flag){
    $output .= '<i class="fas fa-check fa-lg text-success row-center"></i>';
}else{
    $output .= '<i class="fas fa-times fa-lg text-danger row-center"></i>';
}
```

This should give you one icon per row and green if any meets the requirements, else red.

Comment: Thank you kindly sir!